# An ungreedy regular expression to fetch title from a page

Tags: c#, .net, regex, greedy

I want to get the title of a web page using C#. So i'm requesting that page and getting the response page and using a regular expression to extract the title.

string regex = @"(?<=)([\s\S]*)(?=)/";

But i saw a site having two titles such as

```
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="...."/>
<title>Page Title</title>
```

So when i use the above Regex i get the title as

```
Page Title</title><link href="...."/><title>Page Title
```

I know that Regular expressions are greedy. How to modify the Regex as ungreedy so that it gives me "Page Title"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ungreed your `*` you can use `*?`

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfect. Dint know it is that simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=(<\s*title\s*>))((\s|\S)*?)(?=<\s*\/\s*title\s*>)
```